# Criar linhas com caracteres aleatórios no Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

Boa tarde, queria fazer com que o arduino digispark digitasse uma linha com 8 caracteres aleatórios e pulasse para a outra linha fazendo a mesma coisa, só que não sei como controlar o tamanho para isto…

```
`#include “DigiKeyboard.h”

String aleatorio[] = {“0123456789”};
void setup() {
// don’t need to set anything up to use DigiKeyboard
}

void loop() {

DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);
DigiKeyboard.print(aleatorio[random(0, 10)]);
DigiKeyboard.delay(1000);
}`
```

Comment: Atenção que as aspas duplas que tem no código são aspas duplas de editor de texto tipo word e não as que se usam em programação. O `DigiKeyboard.print` espera que tipo ? uma `String` ? Era nesse print que você queria enviar uma `String` com 8 carateres ?

Comment: pode ser uma string só que no máximo ele deve ter 8 caracteres, nesse programa ele cria os números aleatórios só que não para de escrever, eu precisaria que ele escreve os 8 e pulasse pra outra linha e escrevesse 8 assim por diante

Comment: Neste momento não tenho como testar mas isso pode ser feito de várias maneiras, sendo que uma mais dentro do mundo do arduino seria [esta](https://pastebin.com/MAfY0LJH). Naturalmente é necessario testar e ver se alguma coisa está fora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui

`#include "DigiKeyboard.h"
char aleatorio[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxz0123456789"}; // 0 a 33
char aleatorioNumeros[] = {"0123456789"}; // 0 a 9
char retirada[6];
void setup() {
}
void loop() {
DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
 retirada[i] = aleatorioNumeros[random(0,9)];
}

  DigiKeyboard.println(retirada);
  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_ENTER);
  DigiKeyboard.delay(500);
}`